# Not able to load component into page - Angular 4/Ionic 3

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

A button is displayed on the page. When the user selects the button the child component will appear, however, the following error appears - Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No component factory found for ModalComponent. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?

The structure I have set up is as follows and this is in conjunction with Ionic 3 -

```
app (folder) 
 - app.module
 - app.component

components (folder)
 - modal-component.ts

pages (folder)
 - pageOne (folder)
   - pageOne.module
   - pageOne.ts
```

I put the modal component in the pageOne.module

pageOne.module

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        pageOne,
        modalComponent

    ],
    entryComponents: [
        modalComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        IonicPageModule.forChild(pageOne),
    ],
    exports: [
        pageOne,

    ]
})
export class pageOneModule {}
```

pageOne.ts

```
@IonicPage()

@Component({
  selector: 'pageOne',
  templateUrl: 'pageOne.html',

})
export class pageOne {}
```

Comment: are you trying to use any component inside `pageOne.ts`

Comment: are you doing it for a lazy loaded module ?

Comment: yes I am doing both

Comment: Try to remove  `entryComponents: [
        modalComponent
    ],`

Comment: getting the same error

Comment: @userlkjsflkdsvm can you provide a github repo of your demo so that i can look into and see where actualy issue it is

Comment: Yes show more code and should be easy to point out the issue!

Comment: I would recommend using a stackblitz to demo it.
https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Did you import your component in the pageOne.module.ts?

Comment: yes I did import my component in page one module ts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you bootstrapping your module?

put this somewhere where it will load

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { pageOneModule } from './pages/pageOne/pageOne.module';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(pageOneModule)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```

I would also suggest using the angular cli, It does this kind of stuff for you.

Comment: Still getting the same error. Placed this in my app.module

Comment: I think the problem is that it's not getting loaded, if you put a console log after the catch I don't think it will ever get called. I would suggest making an empty project with the cli so you can get an idea of how ppl structure angular 2 apps. I think the main idea your missing in an Entry point, this is normally setup in .angular-cli.json (if using the cli), webpack-config.js (if using webpack) or however your module loader does it. I don't know if ionic has their own way of doing this, I've never used it.

Answer (score 0):

Your Page module isn't setup right for lazy loading. I'm not sure exactly what's causing the exact error but when you lazy load you don't export or declare the entry components. Change your page module to:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        pageOne,
        modalComponent ],
    imports: [ IonicPageModule.forChild(pageOne) ]
})
export class pageOneModule {}
```

Now, you didn't post your modal component code so I'm not sure if it's something you made or not. If it's something like the Material2 Modals, those need to be in entryComponents. Also, your Nav stacks should use the string name of the page now, not a import to make sure you are loading the same object vs cloning it.

Comment: If you look at my above comment I removed the entry component and have done exactly what you mentioned currently. I created the modal component code.

Comment: are you also exporting pageOne still?

Comment: Yeah, Don't do that. If you are lazy loading the module the call to `IonicPageModule` registers it with Ionic. My guess is you're exporting it and then importing it in your main app so it's a singleton.. I'm not totally sure though without seeing the html for pageOne and your app.ts